# Can I pipe commands with Make, but only if they succeed

Tags: shell, makefile

I’m writing a small framework where the flow is conceptually like this:

```
cat input.txt | ./first.sh | ./second.sh > output.txt
```

Please excuse the useless use of `cat` here; it just makes it clearer.

But I want several other properties:

- if any of the scripts fail (return code not zero), its input is passed through to the next script as if it wasn’t there
- ideally, we cache intermediate steps to avoid redoing work.

It’s not hard to write from scratch.

But it feels like someone must have done this before, perhaps with Make, but I haven’t found it yet. Suggestions for patterns with Make?

Comment: I know of no standard tool that can perform pipelines such that _if any of the scripts fail, its input is passed through to next script as if [the failing script] wasn't there_.  Remember that a pipeline works by having the shell set up all the processes with pipes between them, then running them all at the same time.  The shell has no control over what those commands do at failure.  It's not the case that the shell will run one command and cache up its output, then run the next command, etc.

Comment: Indeed, it would not be hard to write from scratch. What *would* be hard, or at least tedious, is writing code with explicit named pipes to *allow* running the commands concurrently, which is what pipe syntax simplifies. If you don't want pipe behavior, don't write pipelines.

Comment: However, if `first.sh` might fail *before* starting to read from `cat input.txt`, you could use something like `cat input.txt | { ./first.sh || cat; } | ./second.sh > output.txt`. If `./first.sh` fails "early", then `cat` will be executed and read all of the input from `cat input.txt`, writing it directly to `./second.sh`.

Comment: > _as if it wasn’t there_ : You mean that the next element in the pipe would see an empty input in this case? This could only be simulated by writing wrappers: Instead of `X|Y`,  write `wrapper X|wrapper Y`, where your script _wrapper_ runs its argument (X, Y, whatever), collects its stdout in a file and prints the file only when the argument script has finished with a zero exit state.

Comment: However, my feeling is that we have a [XY Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) here. In particular the _empty input_ requirement smells fishy. At least I can't right now imagine a situation, where such a behaviour would be convincingly an advantage. Perhaps a redesign of your script would be advisable.

Comment: I take you to mean that if one of the commands in the pipeline fails, the data flow past it as if that command had been `cat` with no arguments -- the input to that command is passed through unchanged to the next command.  It would not necessarily be hard to write a wrapper that adapted other commands to that mode (supposing that the wrapper itself never fails), but it would need to buffer an arbitrary amount of input and output, which is a potential practical problem.  And it would serialize the operation of the pipeline, which is another.

Comment: The shell and `make` have been around a very long time, so I wouldn't necessarily bet against someone having done what you describe before, but it sounds like you don't appreciate how very odd a thing it is that you propose.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the other comments, you can't run them in parallel, as one might not fail until *after* it has already piped some output to the next script.   So pipes would be out.  Given that, you can temporary files.   Something like this would work:

```
output.txt:
   ./first.sh < input.txt > .first.txt || cat input.txt > .first.txt
   ./second.sh < .first.txt > .second.txt || cat .first.txt > .second.txt
   rm .first.txt
   ./third.sh < .second.txt > $@ || cat .second.txt > $@
   rm .second.txt
```

So if `first.sh` fails, anything it output so far is replaced with  nothing.  If `second.sh` fails, it overrides its output with whatever the first step output (either nothing or the proper output), and if `third.sh` fails, it outputs whatever the second step output.   I believe this is what you are after.

Comment: If I understand the question correctly, the fallback in the first step should be `cp input.txt .first.txt` (or similar via `cat`), not `echo > .first.txt`.

Comment: Ahh yes -- thanks.  I'll fix that.